Was Hagar the only person in Hebrew Bible to name God with an attribute?
We read about Hagar's encounter with Angel of the Lord on her  flight from the tent of Abraham , in Gen 16:13 ( Orthodox Jewish Bible):

And she called the Shem of Hashem Who spoke unto her, El Roi (G-d Who Sees); for she said, Have I also here seen after Him that seeth me?

https://www.faithward.org/women-of-the-bible-study-series/hagar-the-woman-who-named-god/ says that Hagar is the only person in Hebrew Bible to name God with with an attribute . Is that a fact ?

It may be a fact that the Bible does not describe anyone else as "naming" God with an attribute, but at least one other did invoke (or "called on", "proclaimed") God with an attribute, in effect giving God a name not in evidence previously. For example:
Genesis 21

33 Abraham planted a tamarisk at Beer-sheba, and there he invoked by
name the Lord, God the Eternal/Everlasting (el-olam).

However, as far as I can see, no other person "named" God in the way that Hagar did, using the formula that biblical mothers often did in naming their sons. (e.g. Gen. 29-30)
